# Failed to run the google app engine PHP demo with dev_appserver locally

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I'm setup the PHP environment with google app engine locally for development, the hello world example is works fine(https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/helloworld).

But when I try to run the demo(F:\GAE\google_appengine\demos\php\minishell\reset.php and F:\GAE\google_appengine\demos\php\minishell\shell.php), got below errors:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in F:\GAE\google_appengine\php\sdk\google\appengine\runtime\RemoteApiProxy.php on line 92

Warning: file_get_contents(http://localhost:54502): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in F:\GAE\google_appengine\php\sdk\google\appengine\runtime\RemoteApiProxy.php on line 92

Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at F:\GAE\google_appengine\php\sdk\google\appengine\runtime\RemoteApiProxy.php:92) in F:\GAE\helloworld\reset.php on line 21

Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at F:\GAE\google_appengine\php\sdk\google\appengine\runtime\RemoteApiProxy.php:92) in F:\GAE\helloworld\reset.php on line 21

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at F:\GAE\google_appengine\php\sdk\google\appengine\runtime\RemoteApiProxy.php:92) in F:\GAE\helloworld\reset.php on line 24

Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in F:\GAE\google_appengine\php\sdk\google\appengine\runtime\RemoteApiProxy.php on line 92

Warning: file_get_contents(http://localhost:54502): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in F:\GAE\google_appengine\php\sdk\google\appengine\runtime\RemoteApiProxy.php on line 92
```

How to fix it?

Comment: What does session_start have to do with file_get_contents?

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using? Are you using 1.8.1?

Comment: This should be 1.8.1. I am also seeing this error.